# Dynamically change the embedd form field value - Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a question about Symfony embed form. Basically i have form called `Media`. `Media` field will save user image, product image and etc.

Media Scheme:

```
Media:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~    
  columns:
    entity:
      type: string(60)
      notnull: true
    entity_id:
      type: bigint(20)
      notnull: true
    file:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
```

Here,

- `entity`    = product or user or etc
- `entity_id` = product_id or user_id or etc

So, i want to change entity values dynamically depends upon where i am calling these form.

```
 $this->embedForm('media', new MediaForm());
```

So, i want to change the field value from here or Advice me if there is any better way.

Comment: Do you want to change the value of the embeded form's field after the form is submitted or when the form is presented to the user for creation/modification?

Comment: @pankar: Yes your correct i want to change the embeded form's field after the form is submitted. Because than only i will get entity id like (user id, product id).

Comment: I think you should override the `doSave()` (you need copy code from the parent) or `saveEmbeddedForms()` (copying not needed) method of the parent form.

Comment: @1ed: Can you give me sample or psudo code as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save a Media object an id is needed, so save can be done after the "parent" object was saved. I think the best option you have is the `saveEmbeddedFroms()` method (in the form which the MediaForm is embedded into):

```
public function saveEmbeddedForms($con = null, $forms = null)
{
  if (isset($this->embeddedForms['media']))
  {
    $mediaForm = $this->getEmbeddedForm('media');

    if ($mediaForm instanceof MediaForm && $mediaForm instanceof sfFormDoctrine)
    {
      $mediaFrom
        ->getObject()
        ->set('entity', get_class($this->getObject()))
        ->set('entity_id', $this->getObject()->get('id'))
      ;
    }
  }

  parent::saveEmbeddedForms($con, $forms);
}
```

Actually you can put this into the `BaseFormDoctrine` class as well, so every doctrine form which has an embedded MediaForm will be saved correctly.

### Edit: Finally *sfFormObject* works for me

```
public function saveEmbeddedForms($con = null, $forms = null)
{
  if (null === $con)
  {
  $con = $this->getConnection();
  }

  if (null === $forms)
  {
  $forms = $this->embeddedForms;
  }

  foreach ($forms as $form)
  {

    if ($form instanceof sfFormObject)
    {
      $form->getObject()->set('entity', get_class($this->getObject()))->set('entity_id', $this->getObject()->get('id'));
    }    


  }
  return parent::saveEmbeddedForms($con, $forms);
}
```

Comment: I am getting error like $mediaFrom is undefined on $mediaFrom->getObject() line. Do you have any clue. Please help me out

Comment: The meda form should be embedded (`$this->embedForm('media', new MediaForm());`) in the configure method. I don't know how could it be undefined because there is an `isset($this->embeddedForms['media'])` call to check if it's defined or not. The embedded `MediaForm` should be a descendant of a doctrine form (`sfFromDoctrine` or actually a `BaseMediaFrom` generated by doctrine). I have updated my answer to check this as well.

Comment: @led: still i am getting undefined error.While i am echo getEmbeddedForm output it simply returns full media form not an object. So i guess there may be the problem.